# How to check if a user is already login in the LDAP server

Tags: session, ldap, single-sign-on

Assume a user uses the domain name and password to login his personal computer, and then i want to get the current user information(such as a session) from the ldap server. Because i would like to use this session to login another web site without password.

I am not sure if i describe this question clearly, i summarize it again as below:
1. User login PC with his password and username
2. The script get this user's session from ldap server and stored
3. When this user want to login another webpage, this website use the session to login (without password)

Is there any ideas about this? i still don't know how to implement with this.

Comment: If it is an intranet website, you can get desired behavor by enabling Windows Authentication on it.

Comment: @paul_sh: If the website implements that, yes. Which many sites don't do, even if they are "intranet" sites. But yes, Windows Authentication is an SSO solution, so if the sites implement that, that would help. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware LDAP does not have a concept of a session on the level of authenticating the people in the directory (as opposed to authenticating access to the LDAP server). So the answer is that you don't. LDAP is typically only used to store the user information.

What you need is some sort of single sign-on (SSO) solution. It can use LDAP to store the user data of course.

Comment: My purpose is to login a website without a password by the current user who has already logined the machine, dose the SSO helpful?

Comment: @jimwan: That is the whole point and indeed the definition of SSO. One login to several sites. Note that both sites need to implement the same SSO solution.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Lennart. From LDAP, there is no mechanism to determine if the user is already bound.

There maybe some extensions or controls or SASL mechanisms that could provide that information from some LDAP server vendor implementations.
-jim